# Where should I put other components (like .mdb) in Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new in Netbeans, I am doing project which is manipulate with MS Access Database (.mdb or .accdb).

Inside my code, I need to write the whole directory of my database file in order to connect it, like: 
`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/abc/def/db.accdb");`

Which folder should I put my database file in so that I no need to write the whole directory to connect it, like: `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://db.accdb");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to hardcode a database path in your code: good point!

Unfortunately, it looks like UCanAccess offers no special folder to automagically find the database: it just tries to find it where it is declared. So if you use a relative path, it will rely on Java processing and Javadoc for `File` class says:

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

If you use shortlinks under window, you can specify a start directory in the shortlink, but I would not rely on it because it is not a common usage even on Windows.

So the correct way (and common usage) is to use an environment variable. This variable would contain the database fullpath if you have no other external configuration value, or it will contain the path of a property file that in turn contains other configuration values.